# Deploy masterpage to subsite using module

Tags: error, content-deployment, module, sub-site

I created a search-center and want to apply a custom masterpage to it. I want to deploy the masterpage using a module and the feature of my solution. I created a module and the Elements.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="SearchcenterModule" Url="Suche/_catalogs/masterpage">
       <File Path="SearchcenterModule\minimal.master" Url="minimal.master" />
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

On activating my feature in the site-collection-features I get an error

> (null) "Suche" not found.
>   ...

where "Suche" is the Name of my subsite, i.e. : `http://mysharepoint/Suche`

Of course I can add the file manually but there must be a way to deploy it using the feature-activation.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the solution but, have you tried to set feature scope to web, use default module definition and activation of this module on the Suche subsite?

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="MasterPageModule" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
    <File Url="MasterPage.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="False" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

If it doesn't work, have you tried to use ~Site token?

```
<Module Name="SearchcenterModule" Url="~Site/_catalogs/masterpage">
```

Comment: Thank you for your repsonse. I need to have the feature scope at "Site" so all actual subsites can access the masterpages. With a SearchCenter it is different, though.
The "~Site"-token gives me an error "Can't create Page `~Site`".

Comment: If I'm not wrong you can store master page into catalogs of root web and reuse it on a subsite. All that you need to activate publishing feature and set master page from site settings. It works for SharePoint Server, not for foundation.

Comment: Do I have to set this under SiteCollection Features or in the Central Administration?

Comment: Indeed, you are right!!! It worked!!!

Answer (score 2):

Masterpages and pagelayout can only be deployed to SiteCollections, not sites/subsites.

So your feature needs to be Site scoped. You can always in your FeatureReceiver set the masterpage on a specific `SPWeb`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="SearchcenterModule" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
       <File Url="minimal.master" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

`IgnoreIfAlreadyExists` makes sure you overwrite it when you deploy so new changes appear. `Type="GhostableInLibrary"` makes sure the new masterpage/pagelayout is visible in the Masterpage & Pagelayouts gallery.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I cannot access the masterpages from a SearchCenter.
So, all I can do is to override the masterpage (in my case minimal.master) manually?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer you can add a FeatureReceiver to your feature and in that you can programmatically set the masterpage eg. your SearchCenter.