# Is it possible to deploy MasterPage via module?

Tags: master-page, deployment

So, is it possible?
Tryied a lot of combinations (using google) in my farm-solution. 
Can't get it to work. 
What i did:

```
<Module Name="MasterPages" Path="MasterPages">
  <File Path="CustomMasterPage.master" 
  Url="_catalogs/masterpage/CustomMasterPage.master" Type="Ghostable"/>
  </Module>
```

and with relative path:

```
<Module Name="MasterPages" Path="MasterPages" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
  <File Path="CustomMasterPage.master" 
  Url="CustomMasterPage.master" Type="Ghostable"/>
  </Module>
```

Also was trying with different `Type` attribute values. Seems first configuration to work (no errors while activating feature), but actually new master page is not displayed in master page gallery.
Btw, i use Share Point foundation. I tried [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71458/deploy-masterpage-to-subsite-using-module) topic too, with `Site` and `Web`scope feature.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan, You can deploy custom master page with module. Just make sure it is added to your feature. I have the working for a publishing site/SharePoint 2013. I assumed the name of your module is "MasterPages"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="MasterPages" List="116" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
    <File Path="MasterPages\CustomMasterPage.master" 
Url="CustomMasterPage.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="UIVersion" Value="15" />
      <Property Name="Title" Value="Custom Master Page" />
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="Master Page" />
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Great! That worked. This is weird, cause of i already tried this (with `List` attribute and `Type` value as GhostableInLibrary. But without properties.

Comment: Btw, suspect `Title` property resolved this, i just did not see MasterPage in UI.

Comment: Feature scope should be **Site**